# HTML, headers inside ordered lists

Tags: html, html-lists, html-heading

The headers inside the ordered list inherit the padding from the list ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uvl7.jpg)). How do I prevent this?

```html
<h3>Lorem</h3>
<ol>
<li>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum finibus egestas. Proin ac dui commodo, lacinia nisl sit amet, viverra nunc. Vivamus tempor tincidunt odio in semper. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce facilisis metus a ornare porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ex metus, consectetur ut est non, congue fringilla nisl. Nullam sagittis felis quis facilisis molestie. 
  </p>
</li>

<h3>Ipsum</h3>
 
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum finibus egestas. Proin ac dui commodo, lacinia nisl sit amet, viverra nunc. Vivamus tempor tincidunt odio in semper. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce facilisis metus a ornare porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ex metus, consectetur ut est non, congue fringilla nisl. Nullam sagittis felis quis facilisis molestie.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

An `<h3>` inside of an `<ol>` is invalid HTML.  The [permitted tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) include only `<li>`.  (Note for example how your first `<h3>` is styled correctly, it's outside the `<ol>`.)  The structure should instead be something like this:

```html
<h3>Lorem</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum finibus egestas. Proin ac dui commodo, lacinia nisl sit amet, viverra nunc. Vivamus tempor tincidunt odio in semper. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce facilisis metus a ornare porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ex metus, consectetur ut est non, congue fringilla nisl. Nullam sagittis felis quis facilisis molestie.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
<h3>Ipsum</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum finibus egestas. Proin ac dui commodo, lacinia nisl sit amet, viverra nunc. Vivamus tempor tincidunt odio in semper. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce facilisis metus a ornare porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ex metus, consectetur ut est non, congue fringilla nisl. Nullam sagittis felis quis facilisis molestie.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Of course, this would make your second list start again at 1, which isn't desired behavior in this case.  You can make use of the `start` attribute on an `<ol>` to specify a starting number, allowing you to continue contextually from your previous list:

```html
<h3>Lorem</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum finibus egestas. Proin ac dui commodo, lacinia nisl sit amet, viverra nunc. Vivamus tempor tincidunt odio in semper. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce facilisis metus a ornare porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ex metus, consectetur ut est non, congue fringilla nisl. Nullam sagittis felis quis facilisis molestie.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
<h3>Ipsum</h3>
<ol start="2">
    <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum finibus egestas. Proin ac dui commodo, lacinia nisl sit amet, viverra nunc. Vivamus tempor tincidunt odio in semper. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce facilisis metus a ornare porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ex metus, consectetur ut est non, congue fringilla nisl. Nullam sagittis felis quis facilisis molestie.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I know this solution. If I add e.g. 5 new <li> in the first <ol>, there is still a start="2" command in the second <ol> and I must change it manually.

Comment: @reti: If the data is dynamically loaded then the start value can be dynamically calculated.  If the data is static then the start value is also static.  So I guess I don’t see the downside to this.  What exactly is the issue?

Comment: It's been a long time since I started this topic. Now the issue is no longer relevant for me, but thank you very much for your answers.